# Why do Sitecore security recommendations advise removing/renaming admin aspx pages

Tags: security

As part of Sitecore's Security guide "Securing Experience Platform" there is a suggestion to disable administrative tools (the aspx pages under /Sitecore/admin). Documented here https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/enable-and-disable-an-administrative-tool.html

What is the reason for doing this on a CD environment, since any /Sitecore URLs would be disabled by default anyway surely this is unnecessary?

Comment: I imagine because some people make mistakes. Documenting every measure possible to ensure a secure website helps avoid those mistakes.

Comment: I'm slightly concerned how you would arrive at a "correct answer" for this question. Not many if any of us can speak to "why" questions.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I really don't see why this is opinion-based? Surely there are a number of technical reasons why removing/renaming these files is advisable and perhaps explaining a few of these could help people in understanding and implementing security recommendations.

Comment: As with all security measures, it's about reducing the attack surface. You rely on just a single point of defense with your solution; the blocking of /sitecore. But what if someone successfully penetrates another vulnerability and is able to say... execute maybe a Server.Transfer or reach those aspx files by other means?

Comment: The only way to prove it and answer your question, would be to list out existing exploits and weaknesses in the Sitecore infrastructure and listing them here. Which would be inappropriate for a lot of other reasons.

Comment: In general; security recommendations are to be followed. Not questioned. I guess that's the underlying point here. And if you don't, guess where the finger points when things go bad :P

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that the main reason to completely remove the admin pages from the CD environment (and other environments where they are not needed) is related to a critical vulnerability (SC2019-001-302938) that was shared publicly in [this](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0760963) Security Bulletin in January 2019 and that was directly affecting one of these pages.

> Vulnerability is applicable to all Sitecore systems running affected versions. This includes CMS-only and xDB-enabled modes, single-instance and multi-instance environments, Managed Cloud environments, and all Sitecore server roles (content delivery, content editing, reporting, processing, publishing, etc.), which are exposed to the internet and have the pages under /sitecore/admin path accessible to Sitecore users.

A security patch was immediately made available when the security bulletin was published. But, of course, what code can be safer than a code that doesn't exist? If you don't need an utility admin page on a server with internet access, it is safer to remove it completely and temporary add it only when needed.